# Wordpress site not redirecting properly

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, bluehost

We have developed a wordpress site recently, if i just type http://example.com in browser i will get the site, but if i type www.example.com it is not displaying anything, what happened to it, is there any problem to my htaccess? My site url and homeurl is http://example.com, i have tried with different options in my htaccess badluck, i just wnat to redirect the www.example.com to http://example.com.

Comment: Does both "example.com" and "www.example.com" have DNS pointing to the same server, and does that server know to serve both hostnames to the same root?

Comment: yes, we are using godaddy, there is an option to that purpose but above scenario is not working, other sites are working perfectly in the same bluehost

Answer (score 0):

for redirecting www to no-www put this code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and make sure your site URL in wordpress setting have no www .